# Pagenotes and printing

Tags: page-breaking, memoir, pagenote

I'm working on a collection of questions for an anatomy course. For most of the questions there will be a collection of "inputs/answers" made as pagenotes ...which works out nice, but...

I'm looking for way to print each chapters pagenotes on a new page and continuously as it's automatically done. Because I want to take out the relevant pages from the .pdf for publishing piece by piece during the course (After each lesson).

Is there a way to define this as I defined at danish translation/alteration of the note title.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}

\renewcommand{\notesname}{Input til svar på opgaver}

\begin{document}
...
\frontmatter

\mainmatter

What is the head attached to? \pagenote{The trunk.}

\backmatter
\appendix
    \printpagenotes*
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may redefine `\pagenotesubhead` to use `\chapter*` plus `\notesname` (and redefine `\notedivision` to do nothing).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}

\makepagenote

\renewcommand{\notesname}{Input til svar på opgaver}
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{}
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[3]{\chapter*{\notesname\ to #1 #2 #3}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

Some text.\pagenote{A pagenote.}

\chapter{Second}

Some text.\pagenote{Another pagenote.}

\printpagenotes*

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant - exactly what I needed. Thank you!